# codeigniter remove index.php form url

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am trying to remove "index.php" from url in Codeigniter. I know how to remove index.php from base url like this **example.com/controller**.

But i don't know how to remove "index.php" in sub folder like **example.com/folder/index.php/controller**

Because i have to different projects in codeigniter. so second project i have uploaded in sub folder.

**.htaccess**

```
#original
#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

#modify
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The above program for base url. So what i will change in this program it work on sub folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this code in your .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /folder/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Example : example.com/folder/index.php/contorller

after above code no need to write index.php

it's working..

Answer (score 0):

Update this variable in config.php `$config['index_page'] = '';`. Remove `index.php`

Comment: This alone will not remove the index.php from your URL, you will need to use some form of mod_rewrite such as a htaccess file to have it properly removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
 `Step:-1  Open the file config.php located in application/config path.  Find and Replace the below code in config.php  file.
```

//  Find the below code

```
 $config['index_page'] = "index.php"
```

//  Remove index.php

```
 $config['index_page'] = ""
```

Step:-2  Go to your CodeIgniter folder and create .htaccess  file.

Path:

```
  Your_website_folder/
  application/
  assets/
  system/
  user_guide/
  .htaccess <--------- this file
  index.php
  license.txt
```

Step:-3  Write below code in .htaccess file

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Step:-4  In some cases the default setting for uri_protocol does not work properly. To solve this issue just open the file config.php located in application/config and then find and replace the code as:

//  Find the below code

```
  $config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO"
```

//  Replace it as

```
 $config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI" `
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the exact same steps you did on your folder for example.com to remove index.php from the base url on the example.com/folder folder. That is, edit/create the htaccess, removing index.php from config file, etc.

Answer (score 0):

#### Quick solution

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP} off
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

#### If facing problem

You might have to check if `modrewrite` is installed and enabled in your `apache`.

**Enable modrewrite**

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Also make sure

```
sudo vi /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

And allow symbolic link

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Restart `apache2` and your `.htaccess` should be working fine.

[image]

Read the last step at: https://www.inteligentcomp.com/2017/07/how-to-setup-and-configure-lamp-on-ubuntu-server.html