# remove index.php codeigniter in localhost/folder/my_codeigniter/

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have try a few solution from any source, but still cannot remove index.php if my project in other folder like : **http://localhost/project/my_codeigniter**, all .htaaccess and configuration work fine if my project in **http://localhost/my_codeigniter**.

hope you can help me, thanks!

Comment: `cannot remove index.php if …` how does this problem manifest?

Comment: @greybeard cannot access any controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a .htaccess file on your project root folder. File content like this;

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /your-project/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: work! thanks brother! -> 'RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ /project/my_codeigniter/index.php/$1 [L]'
i have see something like this in https://stackoverflow.com/a/39673870/5614176, but forget replace 'your-project' by full project path base on localhost, thanks!

Comment: Not important. Can you mark it as an answer? Thanks.